# Completely different home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where my homepage is significantly different from other pages. SO can you suggest how I should use my layout?

Comment: sorry but your question is incredibly unclear. What do you mean by how i should use my layout?

Comment: We would have to see the home page and the general layout of the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the layout for all actions in a controller with the following code:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  layout "my_layout"
  ...
end
```

You can change the layout for a specific action using the following code:

```
def ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def action
    ...
    # to render "app/views/things/action"
    render :layout => "my_layout"
    # or to render a specific view
    render "pages/something", :layout => "my_layout"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you are asking about how to manage multiple layouts for your project. What you could do is simply adding your layouts inside the layout directory and by referencing the one you want to use by adding this line to the controller:

```
layout "name_of_your_layout"
```